# Uncaught ReferenceError: 'xxxxxx' is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Trying to pass a data via onclick  event and keeps saying  "Uncaught ReferenceError: 'xxxxxx' is not defined"

```js
   var ViewDetails = function (insuredID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Exposure/ViewDetails",
            data: {'InsuredID': insuredID},
            success: function (response) {
              
            }
        })
    }
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-success" onclick="ViewDetails(@item.Identifier)">
```

Comment: If you must use onlick, then you probably want it to be `onclick="ViewDetails('@item.Identifier')"` as `@item.Identifier` probably = '"xxxxxx"` - check the *rendered* HTML and you'll see `onclick="ViewDetails(xxxxx)"` but you need ``onclick="ViewDetails('xxxxx')"``

Comment: Note for future reference, don't redact important details. The important detail in this question is exactly what `xxxxx` is referring to.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's not clear that it is redacted (though probably), either way, if it was "abc" it would give the same error just `'abc' not defined` as the issue is they're putting a string into the HTML without enclosing it in quotes (which is not *explained* in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="button_class btn-sm btn-success" data="@item.Identifier">

$('.button_class').click(function() {
  const data = $(this).attr('data');
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Exposure/ViewDetails",
    data: {'InsuredID': data},
    success: function (response) {
              
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.   See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).